How to replace NULL in dataframe with 0?
I have a program that allows users to import .csv file, and select axes to graph from that file. The program works when the data contains all numeric numbers; however, when there are NULL values, I get the following error: Can't combine length  and colors .
An example of data I am having trouble with is included below:



length
y
time
colors




5
0
30
NULL


10
1
60
NULL


15
2
90
NULL



If I remove the colors column, the program will work fine, so I know the program will work if there are only numbers. I think I would need to use a replace() function.
library(shiny)#load and attach package shiny
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

not_sel <- "Not selected"

main_page <- tabPanel(#create a tab panel for main_page
  title = "Data Plotter",#main_page tab titled Plot
  titlePanel("Data Plotter"),#panel titled Plot
  sidebarLayout( #create a layout with a sidebar and main area
    sidebarPanel(#side panel = inputs
      title = "Inputs",
      fileInput("csv_input","Select CSV File",accept = ".csv"),#first parameter is ID to call in server, text that appears, condition to accept
      selectInput("x_axis","Select x-axis",choices = c(not_sel)),#creates input in Inputs
      selectInput("y_axis","Select y-axis",choices = c(not_sel), selected = not_sel, multiple = TRUE),
      actionButton("run_button","Apply Changes",icon = icon("play")), #adds play icon
    ),
    mainPanel(#main panel are outputs
      tabsetPanel(#can divide output into separate viewable screens
        tabPanel(#first screen called Plot
          title = "Plot",
          plotOutput("plot_1") #make Plot screen output image
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
about_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "About",
  titlePanel("About"),#create a panel containing an application title
  "Created by NC",
  br(),#new line
  "June 2024"
)

ui <- navbarPage(#create a page with a top level navigation bar
  title = "Data Plotter",
  theme = shinytheme('sandstone'),
  main_page,
  about_page
)

server <- function(input, output){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
  
  data_input <- reactive({ #wraps following expression as reactive, meaning result changes over time
    req(input$csv_input)#req ensures there is csv input, otherwise does not run
    fread(input$csv_input$datapath)#fast reads input$csv$data path, which is file pathway
  })
  
  data_input_long <- reactive({
    pivot_longer(setDF(data_input()), cols = -y, names_to = "Tag", values_to = "Values")
  })
  
  data_filtered <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    filter(data_input_long(), Tag %in% input$y_axis)
  })
  
  observeEvent(data_input(),{#wraps code and allows it to run when specific reactive expression changes
    choices <- c(not_sel,names(data_input()))#create variable "choices", with not_sel at top and the names of data table next
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "x_axis", choices = choices)#updates the selectinput, which in turn changes the choices
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "y_axis", choices = choices)
  })
  
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data_filtered(), aes(x = .data[[input$x_axis]], y = Values, color = Tag))+
      geom_point()
  }) #assigns renderPlot to output, renders graph for plot_1
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)#creates Shiny application, user interface is layout of app, server is connection between input and output



In your data_input reactive function you can replace all NULL values with 0 as follows:
data_input <- reactive({
  req(input$csv_input) # req ensures there is csv input, otherwise does not run
  dt <- fread(input$csv_input$datapath, na.strings = c("NULL", "")) # fast reads input$csv$data path, which is file pathway
  dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0 # replace NA values (including "NULL" strings) with 0
  dt
})

Here, na.strings = c("NULL", "") in fread specifies that both "NULL" and empty strings should be treated as NA.
Then, the dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0 line replaces all NA values in the data table with 0.
I am unable to test at the moment, but I'm sure this should work

An approach with replace
transform(df, colors=replace(unlist(colors), is.null(unlist(colors)), 0))
  length y time colors
1      5 0   30      0
2     10 1   60      0
3     15 2   90      0

Note that colors is a list of NULLs (because a NULL vector gets reduced to NULL), therefore using unlist to get a vector.
Using @DaveArmstrong's data
df <- structure(list(length = c(5, 10, 15), y = c(0, 1, 2), time = c(30, 
60, 90), colors = list(NULL, NULL, NULL)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")


You should be able to do this with ifelse() and replace NULL values with 0.
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble::tribble(
  ~length,  ~y, ~time,  ~colors,
 5, 0,  30, NULL,
10, 1,  60, NULL,
15, 2,  90, NULL)
d <- as.data.frame(d)
d <- d %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(colors = ifelse(is.null(colors), 0, colors))
d
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   length     y  time colors
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1      5     0    30      0
#> 2     10     1    60      0
#> 3     15     2    90      0

Created on 2024-06-21 with reprex v2.1.0
